# Send Telegram message as a user

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to know if it possible to send message to my telegram bot as a user.
Maybe I should send a request with my credentials? Or I am completely missing something?

UPD:
Ok I see it is not clear. I want to send message using program.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please explain more.

Answer (score 1):

Open your Telegram App, search for your bot and open the chat with it. Then type a message and hit send.